# Ubuntu via Multipass on a Mac (M1 max): connection reset by peer

Tags: mac, multipass

I am playing around with something at the moment which is optimised to work with Ubuntu.

I got myself Multipass to run Ubuntu shell, all works etc etc.

Except, cloned the repo, and when I run "make install" as per the instructions, I get a "tcp error: connection reset by peer"

```
ubuntu@primary:/home/kuji/kujira-core$ make install
go install -tags "netgo ledger" -ldflags '-X github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/version.Name=kujira -X github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/version.ServerName=kujirad -X github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/version.Version=0.3.0 -X github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/version.Commit=aca7081f04a070a8a052be1fd2cfd69403de79a1 -X "github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/version.BuildTags=netgo,ledger"' ./cmd/kujirad
verifying cloud.google.com/go@v0.100.2/go.mod: cloud.google.com/go@v0.100.2/go.mod: Get https://sum.golang.org/lookup/cloud.google.com/go@v0.100.2: read tcp 192.168.64.2:59412->142.250.200.49:443: read: connection reset by peer
make: *** [Makefile:64: install] Error 1
```

This is 100% a problem with my local setup / multipass as the codebase is well known and works.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Just realised the blockquote error doesn't load in full on mobile, so here it is as normal:

Comment: actually can't as not enough characters - anyway, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Don't try to use "Add comment" to add new information. Instead, use the [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1414799/edit) link. Making sure that your details are complete, accurate, and legible will increase the chances that someone will be able to answer your question.